# Adding url to nofitications

Tags: php, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm using phonegap build to create an app.
I've used a plugin for collection ids for sending push notifications, and also a plugin to register url schemes.

I have decided to use Google GCM service to send the notifications (I'm using PHP on the server).

When I create the notification message I can send the title and the message in the data json. But I also want to include a url for deep linking, something like:

```
myweirdapp://show.html?uid=467
```

How can I do that?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use `data` json field to put your custom data in. See https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref#downstream

Answer (score 0):

The WonderBird answer is almost correct.

You do need to add the data to the Json you are sending to GCM.

Then in your app you need to read this data if the notification was pressed and parse the result.

For instance, let's say you wanted to refer users to a different page. For this you have added to the Json the variable page=somepage.html

In the app you have to check if `e.coldstart` is true and then do something like `location.href=e.payload.page`

It's importent to notice that page is inside payload but coldstart is not.